# Excel VBA ListBox only displaying 1 column, not the 8 added columns

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

So I have a listbox (CustomerList) that updates based on my ComboBox Value (CustomerName). I was hoping to have it search and display the listed customer information based ont he combobox text, I can get my "Cust ID" to display and populate as expected, but all of my other columns seem to be MIA or hidden perhaps.

```
   Private Sub CustomerName_Change()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Customer Database")
    Dim Last_Row As Long
        Last_Row = Worksheets("Customer Database").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Me.CustomerName = Format(StrConv(Me.CustomerName.Text, vbLowerCase))
        With Me.CustomerList
            .Clear
            .AddItem "Cust. ID"
            .List(0, 1) = "Customer Name"
            .List(0, 2) = "Customer Business"
            .List(0, 3) = "Customer Address"
            .List(0, 4) = "Customer Phone"
            .List(0, 5) = "Customer Email"
            .List(0, 6) = "Machine Serial#"
            .List(0, 7) = "Machine Serial#"
            .List(0, 8) = "Machine Serial#"
        End With
    Me.CustomerList.Selected(0) = True
        For i = 2 To Last_Row
        For X = 1 To Len(sh.Cells(i, 1))
        a = Me.CustomerName.TextLength
            If LCase(Mid(sh.Cells(i, 2), X, a)) = Me.CustomerName And Me.CustomerName <> "" Then
        With Me.CustomerList
            .AddItem sh.Cells(i, 3)
            .List(CustomerList.ListCount - 1, 0) = sh.Cells(i, 1)
            .List(CustomerList.ListCount - 1, 1) = sh.Cells(i, 2)
            .List(CustomerList.ListCount - 1, 2) = sh.Cells(i, 3)
            .List(CustomerList.ListCount - 1, 3) = sh.Cells(i, 4)
            .List(CustomerList.ListCount - 1, 4) = sh.Cells(i, 5)
            .List(CustomerList.ListCount - 1, 5) = sh.Cells(i, 6)
            .List(CustomerList.ListCount - 1, 6) = sh.Cells(i, 7)
            .List(CustomerList.ListCount - 1, 7) = sh.Cells(i, 8)
        End With
    End If
    Next X
    Next i
    End Sub
```

Have tried declaring column widths aswell, which did not do anything. however when selecting the entry from my listbox the expected boxes populate with the correct customer information.

Comment: did you set the `ColumnCount` property on the listbox?

Comment: @TimWilliams Oof.... I'll take my dunce cap. Completely overlooked the ColumnCount in properties.... thank you!